# Can Opera open saved sessions in the current window?

Tags: opera, window, session

Opening a saved session in Opera creates a new window. Currently, I would prefer to reuse the current window, i.e. to append the saved tabs to the current ones (if any).

Is there a *dedicated* setting or extension that can achieve this?

Note that the Manage Sessions dialog contains an option that does exactly that. However, I'm looking for something that applies when opening sessions from the menu or any toolbar in the main UI. It should also persist, unlike the Manage Sessions option, which resets whenever the dialog box closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very quick reply: See if the Tab Vault extension by Spadija suits your needs.  (I've been away from my computer for nearly 10 months ...)

Comment: Yes, Tab Vault seems to support importing saved sessions, although it does so in a funny way that makes it excruciatingly slow to load them. Others may find it useful, though.